# How to combine multiple rows of same category to one in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to get from table 1 to table 2 from the image but I can't seem to get it right. I tried pivot table to change col A - D from rows to cols. Then I try groupby but it doesn't give me one row but messes up my dataframe instead.

[image]

Comment: `df = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).max()`

Comment: Also, please convert your picture into a reproducible data example that can be used to provide a verifiable answer for you.

Comment: it's not working. i still have 4 rows instead of one

Comment: Please read my second comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fill the null values with the value in the column and drop duplicates:

with :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A", pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan, "Y", "Z"],
              [pd.np.nan, "B", pd.np.nan, "Y", "Z"],
              [pd.np.nan,pd.np.nan, "C", "Y", "Z"]], columns=list("ABCDE"))
df
     A    B    C  D  E
0    A  NaN  NaN  Y  Z
1  NaN    B  NaN  Y  Z
2  NaN  NaN    C  Y  Z

df.ffill().bfill().drop_duplicates()
   A  B  C  D  E
0  A  B  C  Y  Z
```

`df.ffill().bfill()` gives:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  A  B  C  Y  Z
1  A  B  C  Y  Z
2  A  B  C  Y  Z
```

As per your comment, you could define a function that fill the missing value of the first row by the unique value that lies somewhere else in the same column.

```
def fillna_uniq(df, col):
    if isinstance(col, list):
        for c in col:
            df.loc[df.index[0], c] = df[c].dropna().iloc[0]
    else:
        df.loc[df.index[0], col] = df[col].dropna().iloc[0]
    return df.iloc[[0]]
```

You could then do:

```
fillna_uniq(df.copy(), ["B", "C", "D"])
       A  B   C     D       E     F
0  Hello  I  am  lost  Pandas  Data
```

It is a bit faster I think. You can modify your df inplace by passing directly the dataframe, not a copy.

HTH

Comment: but is there a way to optimize this? i'm taking about 15s to perform this filling.

Comment: @user8706644 you could fill only the first row, and instead of drop duplicate, keep only the 1st row. Might be better indeed if you have a huge df.

Comment: I'm actually running on df.groupby(['E,F']).ffill().bfill().drop_duplicates() Does the the custom method work on groups?

Comment: Certainly, a groupby object is just many smaller df on which you apply something. I modify the function a bit, and with this, it works: `df.groupby(["E", "F"]).apply(lambda x: fillna_uniq(x.copy(), ["A", "B", "C", "D"])).reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is using `apply` and `dropna`:

Assuming those blanks in your table above are really nulls:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['Hello',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],'B':[np.nan,'I',np.nan,np.nan],
                   'C':[np.nan,np.nan,'am',np.nan],
                  'D':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'lost'],
                  'E':['Pandas']*4,
                  'F':['Data']*4})

print(df)
       A    B    C     D       E     F
0  Hello  NaN  NaN   NaN  Pandas  Data
1    NaN    I  NaN   NaN  Pandas  Data
2    NaN  NaN   am   NaN  Pandas  Data
3    NaN  NaN  NaN  lost  Pandas  Data
```

Using `apply`, you can apply the lambda function to each column of the dataframe, first dropping null values then find the max:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().max()).to_frame().T

       A  B   C     D       E     F
0  Hello  I  am  lost  Pandas  Data
```

Or if your blanks are really empty strings, then you can do this:

```
df1 = df.replace(np.nan,'')
df1
       A  B   C     D       E     F
0  Hello               Pandas  Data
1         I            Pandas  Data
2            am        Pandas  Data
3                lost  Pandas  Data

df1.apply(lambda x: x[x!=''].max()).to_frame().T

       A  B   C     D       E     F
0  Hello  I  am  lost  Pandas  Data
```